# Windows GUI : attempting a Paint.net style pannel

Tags: windows, user-interface, c++11, window, paint.net

I need to implement a GUI for a 3D modeling app. So far I have implemented a Windows Ribbon menu - now I need to add pannels to add controls to. The best I could find as a model so far are the [Paint.net](http://getpaint.net) control pannels. So I'm looking for something that looks and behaves just like this.

[image: Paint.net UI]

Features I'm looking forward to mimic (all pictured above) :

- Thin border
- Pannel title
- Small top-right close button
- Thin window header
- Conditionnal vertical slider
- The pannels **should always stay on top of main app window**
- The pannels **should not stay on top of other apps in front of the main app window**
- The pannels/windows **should not pop a new item in the windows task bar**
- Transparency on blur is optionnal
- A small footer with buttons would be nice too

So far here is what I achieved (code below) :

[image: App UI so far]

This is a very basic windows - several problems are obvious :

- The window layout is a standard app window layout (thick border + I don't like the rounded edges)
- It has a title but no buttons in it's header
- The vertical scroll bar doesn't hide if unnecessary
- The window **pops it's own icon in the Windows taskbar**
- The window stays on top of **all windowed app**, not just the app main window

The code so far :

```
// Model structure pannel
wndClass.lpszClassName = "StructurePannel";
if (!RegisterClassEx(&wndClass)) return -1;
g_WindowHandlePannelStructure = CreateWindowEx(
    WS_EX_TOPMOST,
    "StructurePannel",
    "Model Structure Pannel",
    WS_BORDER | WS_CAPTION | WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_POPUP | WS_SIZEBOX | WS_VSCROLL,
    CW_USEDEFAULT,
    CW_USEDEFAULT,
    300,
    550,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    hInstance,
    NULL);
```

I'm looking for someone to give me a thorough Paint.net style pannel example - or to point me to a good code example. *I have downloaded the latest open sourced PDN source code* but not sure where to start looking for the code responsible for this part of the UI. An educated direction is welcome too :-)

Comment: I believe you are looking for the `WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW` [extended window style](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff700543(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Hmm I'll check that and let you put this as answer if you are correct - later this evening.

Comment: I'm not sure if that will cover all of the features you want, but it should get you the look and be absent from the task bar.

Comment: Yes this is what I was looking for! Thanks. If you put this as an answer I'll accept it. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `CreateWindowEx(...)` and the [extended window style](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff700543(v=vs.85).aspx) `WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW`should get you the desired appearance of the window frame.

It will also take care of:

- The pannels/windows **should not pop a new item in the windows task bar**

But I'm not sure if/how it will influence the "always on top"-ness.

Comment: "always on top"-ness is achieved by giving the pannel a parent window and `WS_CHILD` style. Now my pannel behaves exactly as I wanted :) Additionnaly, transparency can be set with the `WS_EX_LAYERED` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#layered) extended style and a call to `SetLayeredWindowAttributes(...)` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633540%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Correction : exact window template is : `WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW | WS_EX_LAYERED` as extended styles and `WS_CAPTION | WS_SIZEBOX | WS_SYSMENU` as styles. Allows the close button to display too.